# What team starts on offense in a custom lobby?

Tags: overwatch

When creating a custom Overwatch lobby, and the selected map is an offense/defense map, which of the two teams will start on offense? The Blue or Red team?

I have to setup some lobbies for an esports league tonight and won't have time to test beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got home early so I could test.

- Blue starts on Defense
- Red starts on Offense